# Read list of links with beautiful soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've been trying to read the links from a list of URLs I successfully extracted. My problem is that I get a `TypeError Traceback (most recent call last)` when I try to read the whole list. However, when I read an individual link the `urlopen(urls).read()` line executes without a problem.

```
response = requests.get('some_website')
doc = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
headlines = doc.find_all('h3')

links = doc.find_all('a', { 'rel':'bookmark' })
for link in links:
    print(link['href'])

for urls in links:
    raw_html = urlopen(urls).read()  <----- this row here
    articles = BeautifulSoup(raw_html, "html.parser")
```

Comment: Without the link to the website or the content of `links`, it will be hard to help :/

Comment: that's the link from the website I used https://newspunch.com/category/news/us/
It's for a paper on fake news

Comment: You should update your question with this link to help people to help you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using `BeautifulSoup` with `requests.Session()`, for the efficiency of re-using a connection, and adding header

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with requests.Session() as s:

    url = 'https://newspunch.com/category/news/us/'
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5'}
    r = s.get(url, headers = headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
    links = [item['href'] for item in soup.select('[rel=bookmark]')]

    for link in links:
        r = s.get(link)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
        print(soup.select_one('.entry-title').text)
```